# Python Tkinter Positional arguments with events

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to have arguments and an event listener on a function? I have two entries that I want to clear on `<FocusIn>`. I thought it would be simple and bind delete like `self.minutes.bind("<FocusIn>", self.minutes.delete(0, "end))`, but no that would be too easy. So I created a function to wipe any entry I want whenever focused. My function is simply:

```
def entry_clear(entry, e):
     entry.delete(0, "end")
```

This results in `entry_clear() missing 1 required positional argument: 'e'` but if I use it with `self` it works fine like:

```
def entry_clear(self, e):
     self.minutes.delete(0, "end")
```

But of course now I have to specify the exact entry I want in the function, rather than being used for any entry. Thanks for any help.

Comment: those functions are not that different, you'll need to show more of your code, if you ran the second function under the same circumstances as the first one, you should get the same error, also the passed events should have a `widget` attribute that you can use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not really need to pass the widget itself because `tkinter` passes an `Event` object implicitly with `bind`. This `Event` object has an attribute called `widget` which will be the widget that originally triggered the event. So you can just delete the items of that widget directly:

```
def entry_clear(self, e): # `e` is `Event` object
     e.widget.delete(0, "end")
```

Now to answer your original question:

> Is it possible to have arguments and an event listener on a function?

Yes it is possible, but it depends on how you use `bind`, a fairly common way is like:

```
ent.bind('<1>', lambda event: callback(event, ent))
```

Instead of this, I would always use the first method.